# Core.async: map channel over async function

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, core.async

With Clojure's Core.Async one can map over a channel by using transducers:

```
(def my-chan (chan (buffer 10) (map inc)))
```

But what happens if the mapper function itself is async?

Say, we have a:

```
(defn async-inc [n]
  (let [c (promise-chan)]
    (put! (inc n))
    c))
```

Is there a similar concise way to map the channel over this function? Or would one have to do something like this:

```
(def my-chan (chan (buffer 10)))
(def my-chan2 (chan (buffer 10)))

(go (while true
      (>! my-chan2
          (<! (async-inc (<! my-chan))))))
```

It would not really be mapping, since two channels are needed instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general advice not to create channel inside a function and return it out because it forces user of that function to use core.async. You can either return an output through a [promise](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise) or return through callback function.

Assuming what you want to do with an output from `async-inc` is to print it out using `println` function.

**Return through a promise**

```
(defn async-inc [n]
  (let [p (promise)]
    (deliver p (inc n))
    p))

(println @(async-inc (<! my-chan)))
```

**Return through callback**

```
(defn async-inc [n callback]
  (callback (inc n)))

(async-inc (<! my-chan) println)
```

But if you don't have a control over `async-inc`. Here are your options.

**Use `<!!`**

```
(println (<!! (go (<! (async-inc (<! my-chan))))))
```

or

**Use `take!`**

```
(take! (go (<! (async-inc (<! my-chan)))) println)
```